# Maildir on Debian Squeeze - Finding email boxes on /lost+found

Tags: postfix, dovecot, debian-squeeze, maildir

A server that I'm helping to administrate had a severe file system problem and now there's a lot of files inside the `/lost+found` directory. I'd like to find the `user@example.com`'s **received** and **sent** mail boxes. We're using Maildir email format, Postfix as MTA and Dovecot as POP3/IMAP server on a Debian Squeeze.

I've already tried

```
grep -r ".*user.*"
```

and

```
grep -r ".*From: \"John Doe.*"
```

The majority of the results where files like `1412216683.V804I9e3a201M324743.example` inside directories like `Maildir10805257/new/`. Since there are many different `Maildir/new` directories, I'd like to know if there's a specific one that is the `user@example.com` mailbox and if so, if someone knows a better way to find it. Otherwise, are his remaining messages spread all around these directories?

Comment: I'd use the `Delivered-To:` field to identify the correct owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For received email*, you can rely on **Delivered-To** to identify the correct recipient *as [@sebix](https://serverfault.com/users/217116/sebix) has said [in above comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/681338/maildir-on-debian-squeeze-finding-email-boxes-on-lostfound#comment837160_681338)*.The challenge is, if the email has more than one **Delivered-To** header. So you must modify the grep to search user@example.com mailbox

```
grep -r -m 1 '^Delivered-To:' directory/ | grep user@example.com
```

---

*For sent email*, you can rely on **From** header. Again, you should limit it in first occurrence.

```
grep -r -m 1 '^From:' directory/  | grep user@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks! That really helped me. I was almost giving up, because I was starting to think that each user's mailbox that appeared in the `/lost+found` directory would be split in several `Maildirxxxxxx` directories, which apparently is not the case: using the command you suggested (except for the `-m 1` part), I found another user mailbox where all his received email were inside `Maildirxxxxxx/new` and the received ones in `Maildirxxxxx/.Sent`. So I'd say it's just a matter of digging deeper :)